# nginx: vfprintf %s NULL in syslog

Tags: nginx

I'm running nginx 1.10.2 on OpenBSD 6.0-current. My syslog has occasional entries like this:

```
Nov 29 09:55:25 foo nginx: vfprintf %s NULL in "%s %2d %02d:%02d:%02d%.*s %d%s"
```

I can't figure out what is causing nginx to log these events. Could someone kindly point me in the right direction as to where to look?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see this strings in nginx's source code

Comment: Good point, @AlexeyTen. I just searched PHP's source code as well, and don't if there either. I don't see anything else in the application stack that might be generating the log entry, but that doesn't mean I'm overlooking something. Is it odd that some other code can create log entries masquerading as nginx?

Answer (score 1):

This was [reported on the OpenBSD bugs mailing list](https://marc.info/?l=openbsd-bugs&m=149121476610865&w=4) - looks like it's actually an issue in libcrypto, specifically `/usr/src/lib/libcrypto/asn1/t_x509.c`

[A patch was committed on the 3rd April](https://github.com/openbsd/src/commit/989edf2beff32593661082af36788031725f993d), which missed the release of 6.1, so will be fixed in 6.2.